# USe MSBuild properties in windows batch command line?

Tags: msbuild

defined some msbuild properties, is it possible to 'promote' it to be used in the windows batch file? i.e. in my .bat file write something 'echo %CustomProperty%' where the CustomProperty is defined in the msbuild script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing MSbuild properties within a batch file doesn't seem to be the correct release approach and does not seem necessary. The same facility is easily available within Msbuild itself. In your example case you can use something like the following:

```
<Message Text="Copying $(ZipFile) to $(PublicFolderToDropZip)" Importance="high" />
```

to achieve what you were looking.
You can even run batch files in the following manner:

```
   <Target Name="Default">
    <Exec Command="CALL mybatch.cmd" />
  </Target>
```